# Problema al instalar Manjaro

Tags: linux

Soy bastante novato en esto de Linux.

Estoy tratando de instalar Manjaro 17.0.6 XFCE junto a Windows 10.
El ISO lo corro desde un USB Booteable mediante UEFI en formato GPT. 
Hasta ahi todo bien.

Como el disco dev/sda esta en formato MBR y ya hay tres particiones que utiliza Windows creo una particion nueva extendida para poner las diferentes particiones para instalar Manjaro:

- /boot/efi FAT32 500mb as ESP
- swap 4096mb NO FLAGS
- / ext4 20480mb NO FLAGS
- /home ext4 40960mb NO FLAGS

Se instala todo sin disparar ningun error.

Ahora, cuando reinicio arranca automaticamente con Window 10 como si el GRUB no existiera.

Me fije en la bios y en la prioridad de booteo esta Manjaro, y secure boot y el boot rapido estan desactivados. Tambien esta el modo de booteo esta en UEFI and Legacy.

Creo que el problema esta en querer instalar Manjaro con UEFI en una particion de tipo MBR.

Una opcion que vi en el manual de manjaro, es editar la particion de arranque del propio windows para que instale el grub ahi, pero por defecto dicha particion esta en NTFS y deberia estar si o si en FAT32.

En fin, tengo un lio, realmente no estoy seguro de lo que estoy diciendo ya.

aclaracion: estoy utilizando la instalacion grafica, no la de consola.

ACTUALIZACION

Pude resolver el problema. Instale manjaro por BIOS y no por UEFI.
Lo demas lo hice tal cual, en una partición extendida e instale el grub en el sda como muestra por defecto.

Al parecer en las particiones MBR se hace por BIOS y las particiones GUID por UEFI.

Saludos!

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no es consistente con la temática del sitio.